# Redirecting stdin to children makes the program not terminate

Tags: c, unix, pipe, fork

what I've been trying to do is to set up a program that forks two children. The parent reads from stdin and then redirects it to its child processes via pipes. The child then duplicates the read end of the pipe so that it can read from stdin (instead of the pipe) and then print it into stdout. Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char buf[100];
    int pipe_one[2];
//    int pipe_two[2];

    pipe(pipe_one);
//    pipe(pipe_two);

    // First child
    switch(fork()) {
        case -1:
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        case 0:
            close(pipe_one[1]);
            dup2(pipe_one[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(pipe_one[0]);
            while (fgets(buf, 100, stdin)) {
                fputs(buf, stdout);
            }
            fflush(stdout);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Second child
/*    switch(fork()) {
        case -1:
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        case 0:
            close(pipe_two[1]);
            dup2(pipe_two[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(pipe_two[0]);
            while (fgets(buf, 100, stdin)) {
                fputs(buf, stdout);
            }
            fflush(stdout);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        default:
            break;
    }*/

    close(pipe_one[0]);
//    close(pipe_two[0]);
    FILE *out_1 = fdopen(pipe_one[1], "w");
//    FILE *out_2 = fdopen(pipe_two[1], "w");

    while (fgets(buf, 100, stdin)) {
        fputs(buf, out_1);
//        fputs(buf, out_2);
    }

    fflush(out_1);
//    fflush(out_2);
    fclose(out_1);
//    fclose(out_2);
    close(pipe_one[1]);
//    close(pipe_two[1]);

    wait(NULL);
    //wait(NULL);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I've commented out all the parts relating to the second child. If I run this program, it works flawlessly (it reads from stdin until it meets EOF and then prints it into stdout). However, if I try to do the exact same thing with a second fork (see the parts commented out), it does the exact same thing except that after printing everything the program doesn't terminate. And I haven't been able to find the reason why.

My guess would be that I'm not to duplicate stdinfileno twice in two children. However, our tasks requires us to do so. Is there anything I am missing? I'd be really glad if someone could take a look at it!

Answer (score 5):

The read end of a pipe only reaches EOF once all descriptors to the write end are closed.

You don't close `pipe_two[0]` in the first child, so the second child won't exit until the first one does.

You don't close `pipe_one[0]` in the second child, so the first child won't exit until the second one does.

---

By the way,

It would be nice to close `pipe_two[1]` in the first child.

It would be nice to close `pipe_one[1]` in the second child.

Also,

```
dup2(pipe_one[0], STDIN_FILENO);
close(pipe_one[0]);
while (fgets(buf, 100, stdin)) ...;
```

can be reduced to

```
FILE *f = fdopen(pipe_one[0]);
while (fgets(buf, 100, f)) ...;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I didn't realize that I also have to close the pipes I don't use at all.

Comment: Re "*I didn't realize that I also have to close the pipes I don't use at all.*", That's a weird thing to say since you close `pipe_one[1]` in the first child even though you don't use it.

Comment: Yes, I meant that because I never use pipe_two in the first child, I'd also never have to close it (only the unused ends for pipe_one since this is the one pipe I'm using). But now that I think about it it only makes sense that I have to close everything.